# perform arithmetic on stack driver metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

These aren't custom metrics I'm trying to add just the existing GCP metrics.

How do I add 2 metrics together in a Stack driver time series?

I have two different metrics and I want to sum them so I see a single line- also I'd like to be able to alert on this summed metric too. Is this possible?

Again I'm not shipping metrics to stack driver I'd doing this with existing metrics already there.

Comment: You can use [time series Aggregation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics#aggregating_time_series). Will that suit your needs?

Comment: @Tudormi Thats agging on a single metric- so no. I want to combine several different metrics. Datadog for example makes this easy

Comment: I was thinking that it is not possible for the existing metrics and I considered defining custom ones, but according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource), _points from different monitored resource objects are held in different time series_.  So I don't believe it's possible to create a single line from different metrics. It's worth a [feature request on the public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187228&template=1010839)

Comment: Have you created a feature request? Can you share it here?

Comment: Running into the same need, was this ever discovered to be possible?